# How do I create slices of a topographical mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've been trying to create a topographical wire mesh as shown below to convert to curves later:

[image]

Here I have a Bisect Tool Cut in Blender, but as you can see, the Tools panel really doesn't have an option to Create Multiple Cuts like I would want:

[image]

[image]

But heres an example from Cinema4D below, but I know it's possible in Blender too.

[image]

I would then like to select those edges and convert them into splines.

[image]

Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I am pretty sure, that someone has answered the same question before. Give me some time to search for it.

Comment: @PaulGonet If you can find it, I would greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Art Jr., my answer to [question 10587](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10587/) and [question 34258](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34258) may be of some utility to you.

Comment: @Art Jr. Here you are sir: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39510/how-can-i-slice-an-object-horizontally-into-equal-pieces

Comment: I think this is a case of asking about [Y instead of X](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/311571). You're asking about how to get the knife tool or bisect to do multiple cuts (which is possible), but if you rephrase your question to be more about the effect you want as opposed to the specific tools you want to use I think you will find that there are better solutions than using the knife or bisect.

Comment: @PaulGonet Thank you Paul for your time, but that's not quite what I'm looking for. I'll have to edit this post to avoid confusion.

Comment: @PaulGonet I went ahead and revised my question, as I should've been more clear. I'll see if I can look into it. I know it can be done.

Comment: @RayMairlot I am trying to stay away from any mathematical computations or scripts if the "better solutions" is what you are talking about.

Comment: @RayMairlot I went ahead and revised the question. Hopefully it will be easier to understand what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: do you know about the boolean modifier?

Comment: Does my answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58209/20508) help at all?

Comment: Sverchok has a [node to cut slices](https://youtu.be/H5SYNxykqtM?t=160) like the last example, which could then be extruded to get the top image.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a plane that is larger than your terrain and create an array in the Z direction. Add a Boolean modifier to the terrain - the plane is used as a cutter. Visually you can create the layers by then adding a solidify modifier...

[image: Array + Contour]

...but you asked about creating curves so - apply the Boolean and then in Edit mode press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose by loose parts. Back in Object mode while all the objects are still selected press <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and convert your meshes to curves.

[image: Contours to curves]

Comment: Sorry to pollute this post.
@Patdog
Do you know how to separate each slices and put them on a plane to next export it as svg or jpg.
This is for a laser cutting project.
Thanks.

Comment: There is an addon that automates this - you can read more about it here https://blendscript.blogspot.com/2019/01/blender-28-laser-slicer.html and helpful is this review of the addon https://youtu.be/M4dM9dJxEAo