# Put slices on 2D plane

Tags: mesh, export, image

**Related question:** [How do I create slices of a topographical mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/62874/78972)

I'd like to separate each slice and put them on a plane to generate a svg or jpg for laser cutting.

Does anyone know how to do it?
Thanks in advance :)

Something like this example picture:

[image]

Comment: inkscape can be used to convert raster images to svg

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ShantanuAryan
I maybe non properly explain my request, did you open the link on top of my message ?
A bug delete the comment above it.
I followed the link procedure and would like to separate each slices and put them on a plane to export it as svg or jpg as said.

Comment: ok, so i am assuming you have separated all the slices. you can render out a png image (black bg, white emission on objects), then open the image in inkscape. inside inscape you can trace image to obtain svg and then exoprt the svg to Gcode

Comment: Hello @ARNAUD :). What have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @ShantanuAryan
I no i didn't separate all the slices, that the first thing I want to do.

Comment: @JachymMichal
I' m stuck after the step : set the solidify modifier. I would like each slices to be moved individually to place them on a plane I will export after as a svg or jpg.

Comment: in that case apply the boolean modifier. do not add solidify. go to edit mode, select all, press p > separate by loose parts. arrange all parts on a plane. Should i write this as an answer?

Comment: @ShantanuAryan
I tried that already but when I'm in edit mode the model is not sliced, it appear as a solid/full mesh.